# need linq query to return only the last 100 results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am searching a sql server database and apparently it's returning more than the application can handle. I'm getting back way to many results and I need to minimize the number of records sent back and then tell the user that they have selected too many.

Here is what I have:

```
private List<Log> SearchLog()
{
  try
  {        
    using (var model = new SuburbanPortalEntities())
    {
      var qry = from logs in model.Logs
        where logs.LogDateTime > dateTimePicker_Start.Value &&
              logs.LogDateTime < dateTimePicker_End.Value
        select logs;

      Guid tokenid;
      if (Guid.TryParse(textBox_TokenId.Text, out tokenid))
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.TokenId == tokenid);
      }

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_SessionId.Text))
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.SessionId == textBox_SessionId.Text.ToLower());
      }

      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox_Contains.Text))
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.Message.Contains(textBox_Contains.Text));
      }

      if (checkedListBox_DisplayFilter.GetItemChecked(0))
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.IsWarning);
      }

      if (checkedListBox_DisplayFilter.GetItemChecked(1))
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.IsException);
      }

      var sourceEnumList = new List<string>();
      if (checkBox_WebPortal.Checked)
      {
        sourceEnumList.Add("WebPortal");
      }

      if (checkBox_SubService.Checked)
      {
        sourceEnumList.Add("SubService");
      }

      if (checkBox_TruckRouting.Checked)
      {
        sourceEnumList.Add("TruckRouting");
      }

      if (checkBox_SuburbanHub.Checked)
      {
        sourceEnumList.Add("SuburbanHub");

      }
      if (sourceEnumList.Any())
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => sourceEnumList.Contains(x.SourceEnum));
      }

      qry = qry.OrderByDescending(x => x.LogDateTime);

      return qry.ToList();
    }

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    return null;
  }
}
```

How do I get the LAST 100 records and know to tell the user that they need to refine their search?

Thanks!

Comment: The best way to do this is by reversing the sort order and take the top 100.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
return qry.Take(100).ToList();
```

If you don't sort your records by *descending order* this will give you the first 100 records.But I see you already did the sort,so this should give you the correct result.Anyway,if you want to remove `OrderBy` here is the one line version to avoid confusion:

```
return qry.OrderByDescending(x => x.LogDateTime).Take(100).ToList();
```

Comment: Will that give me the last 100 records? Also, how do I know that they have selected too many?

Comment: yes,that will give last 100 records.If you want to use user choice for number of rows then you can use a parameter, get user choice and pass that parameter to take method.

Comment: ah wait I'm overthinking it, I could just see if the number of records is 100 tyvm for your help!

Comment: @ErocM No, that will give you the first 100 records based on your ORDER BY. If you want the last 100 records using the same, then sort in the opposite direction `OrderBy(x => x.LogDateTime)` and then take the first 100 records using the same `Take(100)`.

Comment: @Selman22: that is the *first* 100 records, not the last. The documentation you link to states that explicitly!

Comment: @DanPuzey he is using `OrderByDescending` before return statement.that's why this will give last 100 records.

Comment: If you look at ErocM's code, he is sorting by descending before returning the query...

Comment: @ErocM don't remove the orderby statement.I didn't write it because you already did.

Comment: @Selman22 I understand the confusion though. You should clarify that he has already done the sort correctly in your answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just change the ordering and take the first 100 ones.

```
qry = qry.OrderBy(x => x.LogDateTime).Take(100).OrderByDescending(x => x.LogDateTime).ToList();
```

UPDATE:

I believe there was some confusion caused by how the question was phrased. What you're really looking for is: `qry.Take(100).ToList();` (and don't change the sort order)

+1 @Selman22

Comment: that will never give the last 100 record.That will take first 100 record then sort them by descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.Take()
```

To limit the number of returned rows. This together with

```
.Skip()
```

allows you to page your results.

Before using Skip and Take I would strongly suggest you use the .Order() command to make sure you are getting the records in the order you want.

If you want to know if there are 100+ records use .Take(101) and see if you get back more than 100 records

```
int page = 0;
int pageSize = 100
var result = dataset.OrderBy( x=> x.somecolumn ).Skip(page * 100).Take(pageSize + 1);

if(result.Count()>pageSize + 1)
     // there are more records than we can display
```